# unable to update the session of next-auth v4 in nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jwt, next-auth, next.js13

I am using nextjs 13 along with next-auth v4. I have my own external express API

**I am using Google sign in provider**

I am calling external API for login and providing me access and refresh tokens and on refresh token expiry I want to get a new access token silently. I am able to fetch the new tokens but unable to update the session with newly fetched tokens.

I referred to the next-auth v4 docs and they have this example

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"

export default function Page() {
  const { data: session, status, update } = useSession()

  if (status === "authenticated") {
    return (
      <>
        <p>Signed in as {session.user.name}</p>
        
        {/* Update the value by sending it to the backend. */}
        <button onClick={() => update({ name: "John Doe" })}>
          Edit name
        </button>
        {/*
          * Only trigger a session update, assuming you already updated the value server-side.
          * All `useSession().data` references will be updated.
          */}
        <button onClick={() => update()}>
          Edit name
        </button>
      </>
    )
  }

  return <a href="/api/auth/signin">Sign in</a>
}
```

When I try the same I get : **typeError : update is not a function**

Comment: Did you find the solution this?

Comment: No. I changed my approach. I am using id_token provided by the google oauth.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where you get this example, but this is `useSession` type:

```
export declare function useSession<R extends boolean>(options?: UseSessionOptions<R>): SessionContextValue<R> | {
    readonly data: null;
    readonly status: "loading";
};
```

It does not have `update` method. If you want to refresh token, you have to make a post request to the provider. Because only provider server can work on the token. [From here](https://next-auth.js.org/v3/tutorials/refresh-token-rotation)

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Providers from "next-auth/providers"

const GOOGLE_AUTHORIZATION_URL =
  "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?" +
  new URLSearchParams({
    prompt: "consent",
    access_type: "offline",
    response_type: "code",
  })

/**
 * Takes a token, and returns a new token with updated
 * `accessToken` and `accessTokenExpires`. If an error occurs,
 * returns the old token and an error property
 */
async function refreshAccessToken(token) {
  try {
    const url =
      "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?" +
      new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        refresh_token: token.refreshToken,
      })

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      method: "POST",
    })

    const refreshedTokens = await response.json()

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw refreshedTokens
    }

    return {
      ...token,
      accessToken: refreshedTokens.access_token,
      accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + refreshedTokens.expires_in * 1000,
      refreshToken: refreshedTokens.refresh_token ?? token.refreshToken, // Fall back to old refresh token
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)

    return {
      ...token,
      error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
    }
  }
}

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Providers.Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorizationUrl: GOOGLE_AUTHORIZATION_URL,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token, user, account) {
      // Initial sign in
      if (account && user) {
        return {
          accessToken: account.accessToken,
          accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + account.expires_in * 1000,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
          user,
        }
      }

      // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
      if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires) {
        return token
      }

      // Access token has expired, try to update it
      return refreshAccessToken(token)
    },
    async session(session, token) {
      if (token) {
        session.user = token.user
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken
        session.error = token.error
      }

      return session
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: I am using my own access and refresh token flow on top of google provider. 

and the above example is present in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you are not wrapping your component in SessionProvider